# artifact identification in irregular-samped data

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, sampling

There is a dataset combined by different datasets a,b,c,d,e. The time intervals are irregular(i1, i2, i3:intervals between a and b, b and c...), but the sampling rate SR in every single dataset is the same.

Because of these irregular intervals i1&i2&i3..and SR, which kind of artifact/alias would be generated in periodicity detection of the combined dataset?